# Loopj Put and Post with basic auth return null response with no error

Tags: json, post, android-asynctask, put, loopj

This is an attempt to use Loopj for a Synchronous put and post call from a HTTP utility class. The code uses a syncrhonous client as it’s used inside an AsyncTask and some UI interactions depend heavily on the json response so the AsyncTask is managing making the call asynchronously. 

All the get calls from the HTTP utility class are working successfully. The post and put do not and they both appear to have exactly the same problem.
The json string is created using Gson. I’ve tested the json output from the application directly in Postman and it posts exactly as expected to the API, so it appears to be well formed and behaves totally as expected without any errors. 

Both the put and post calls are constructed without throwing an error. Basic authorization is being added (as shown on the client instance). The SyncHTTPClient put method is called using a null context parameter. I did a bit of research and found a single post where this was being done successfully.

https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/1139

The put call fires but doesn’t enter either the overridden methods of the handler. It just returns null. I've included a portion of the working class to view:

```
public void executePutSave(String name, String pass, String jsonBody) {
    client.setBasicAuth(name, pass);
    executeLoopJPutCall("/api/Save", jsonBody);
}

public void executeLoopJPutCall(String relativeUrl, String jsonBody) {
    String url = getAbsoluteUrl(relativeUrl);
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonBody, "UTF-8");
    jsonResponse = null;
    client.put(null, url, entity, "application/json", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                    super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                    jsonResponse = response.toString();
                    Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: " + jsonResponse);
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) { 
                    super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
                    jsonResponse = errorResponse.toString();
                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + statusCode + errorResponse );
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently the header must be added explicitly when using the above code to Post or Put json to the API. Once I changed the header authentication line from this:

```
client.setBasicAuth(name, pass);
```

To this:

```
    String userpass = name + ":" + pass;
    String encoded = new String(Base64.encode(userpass.getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
    client.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);
```

...everything worked as expected.

I found the information on this blog: https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/113

Passing a null context worked, too.